# How to get user email by ID on Message extension created using Microsoft Bot Framework?

Tags: node.js, botframework, chatbot, microsoft-teams

I am using Microsoft Bot Framework to create a message extension. I would like to get the user email of customers who enter the search query in the command box. I am able to get the user email id in the normal search, ie in the bottom search and chatbox. But the same method is not working when I search the content using the command box by entering @appname . The following method is used to get the user email id in a normal search

```
export default class MessageExtension extends TeamsActivityHandler {
async handleTeamsMessagingExtensionQuery(context, query) {
   
    let searchQuery = query.parameters && query.parameters[0].name === 'query'
        ? query.parameters[0].value
        : '';

 
    console.log("searchQuery="+searchQuery);   
    console.log("query="+JSON.stringify(query));      

    const member = await this.getTeamMember(context);
        console.log("email="+member);}}

async getSingleMember(context) {
  try {
      const member = await TeamsInfo.getMember(
          context,
          context.activity.from.id
      );
      var email = member.email;
      const message = MessageFactory.text(`You are: ${member.email}`);
      return email
  } catch (e) {
      if (e.code === 'MemberNotFoundInConversation') {
          return context.sendActivity(MessageFactory.text('Member not found.'));
      } else {
          throw e;
      }
  }}
```

Does anyone know how we can get it?

Screenshot of the command box search area

[image: command box area where we enter search]

Answer (score 0):

This is a platform bug. We have raised a request to fix it.